# Can a file .exe.part already have caused damage?

Tags: virus

If on a Windows machine, an antivirus program has found a Win32:Rootkit in a file `...\Temp\...\xy.exe.part`, could the file possibly already have caused damage or not given that it seems to be an "incomplete" file?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're downloading some torrent or some file using a download manager. Unless you (or some other application) somehow executed it, no damage is expected.

Comment: What Adnan said however I am extending this with noting the matter of possible exploits that might have been triggered by scanning it, indexing it etc etc.
It is possible (but highly unlikely) that when the anti-virus opened the file to scan it it caused an exploit of sorts (buffer overflow for example).

Comment: Do you trust the .part file extension? Do you have any other evidence that this is an incomplete file download? Files can be renamed to disguise their intent and this is particularly easy on systems which use the file name extension (Win/Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll agree with @Adnan but I will make a bit longer answer just to explain you what can happen and what is not possible.

**Short answer** is no.

**Long answer**, no, but *maybe*. As you may know, the *.exe.part is un-executable until renamed to executable PE (exe, cpl etc.). Try it out. Create a new file on desktop called "test" and change files extension to `.exe.part`. Now try to run it. Is it executed? I don't think so. It will ask you for software you want to run or open the file with.

Considering above, you are safe but there still might be chances to cause a damage to a system in next case. If connection is established, an attacker maybe already compromised the system with another malware which will hook the process of downloading and rename the file to *.exe. If file is successfully renamed, it will execute the same. Note that this may not be possible because .exe.part did not finish full structure of PE file (it's still in downloading process) plus you were saying something about anti-virus that will detect the infection while downloading. The chances of happening this to someone are pretty low. The only generic trojan that could do something like this is probably Carberp and attacker would not execute this type of action as most of trojans and malwares already offer hidden `UrlDownloadToFile` function which downloads file with out your knowledge of specific action.

As written above, you safe but there is always a way of security disclosure.

Comment: Although as you explain Windows Explorer won't directly execute the file in that state I'm not sure your assertion "un-executable until renamed" is true for the system overall. If another piece of malware is merely looking for the data/code in this file then it may dangerous already.

Comment: Oh, yes, thats for sure @adric. I was thinking about normal execution of PE file. Of course the same .exe.part may consist of code or data that may give particular operation or action, or overall have some specific data. Although that explanation is almost there in "no, but maybe".

Comment: Any file is executable using CreateProcess(), or even from a plain old cmd.exe – it's just Explorer that's picky about extensions.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Try to put a handle to a non-executable file. You will come up with error. The only thing you can do is to read data from file even if it's not executable.